# how to change change the windows 10 login background picture

Tags: image, authentication, background, windows-10

i use windows 10 and wanted to change the background picture displayed during logging in.
It's a standard login picture located at:

```
C:\Windows\Web\Screen\img103.png
```

i've so far found four references to it in the registry but none of them seem to be obviously related to the windows login procedure.

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe\PersistedStorageItemTable\ManagedByApp\{AF250862-DE71-40E1-9837-55F056624302}

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe\PersistedStorageItemTable\ManagedByApp\{AF250862-DE71-40E1-9837-55F056624302}

Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1511638195-1603889089-2464006216-1001\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe\PersistedStorageItemTable\ManagedByApp\{AF250862-DE71-40E1-9837-55F056624302}

Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1511638195-1603889089-2464006216-1001_Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe\PersistedStorageItemTable\ManagedByApp\{AF250862-DE71-40E1-9837-55F056624302}
```

i would like to change that picture to one of my own chosing. preferably through a standard windows GUI dialogue.

thanks in advance for any helpful comments you can direct at me.

Answer (score 0):

Click window key write settings then
Settings > Personalization> Lock screen > Choose your picture > Browse

[image]

[image]

Comment: sorry I'm not talking about my lockscreeen. this picture is personalized as i want it. but even after changing it there my login picture remains the same

Comment: Lock screen is Login screen mine works perfect. Be sure you clicked on lock screen not background

Comment: i can assure you that i can tell apart my background settings from my lockscreen setting. however neither do affect my login screen.

Comment: I updated my answer with login screen with custom background. I can't take screenshot with password field

Answer (score 0):

i dont't know what did in the end. i toggled displaying the lock screen at login, switch lockscreen to windows spotlight, delete contents %USERPROFILE%/AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets
switch lockscreen back from sptlight to image and rebooted. now it displays correctly. i'm flabbergasted.